# An issue with IE (jQuery codes)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have an issue with IE (I want to support IE users Grrrr):

```
$(function () {
    var clonedField = $('.child').clone(),
        main = $('.append');
    $('', {
        text: 'delete',
        class: 'icon-delete',
        href: '#',
        click: function () {
            $(this).parent().remove();
            return false;
        }
    }).appendTo(clonedField);
    $('#add-input').click(function () {
        main.append(clonedField.clone(true));
        return false;
    });
})
```

The error is: `expected identifier, string or number`
Line 142: `href: '#',`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that IE treats "class" as a reserved keyword. Put it in quotes, like this:

```
text: 'delete',
'class': 'icon-delete',
href: '#',
```

This is actually stated on the [$.attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) reference page.

Comment: @MiniNaim We all do :) No problems.